# Why are there no discrete OLEDs?

Tags: oled

Why does nobody make a discrete OLED in an SMT or thru-hole package, like we have with LEDs? Is it a cost thing or a limitation of the process?

Comment: Why would you want one?

Comment: They do http://www.konicaminolta.com/oled/products/

Comment: Ok, let me clarify: Why would you want an OLED in an SMT or thru-hole form factor? What benefit would an OLED provide that a conventional LED doesn't?

Comment: @BrendanSimpson Organic LEDs are a healthier alternative to regular arsenic-laden factory LEDs.

Comment: advantage of OLED is form factor, so no SMD or TH, but large plates for example: https://www.lgoledlight.com

Answer (score 4):

Making an "OLED" and then putting it in a package, like you'd do with a Chip LED is commercially nonsensical from most points of view:

1. It loses its microscopic-application-advantage
2. It adds no flexibility advantage
3. It costs several orders of magnitude more
4. The optical efficiency is lower (due to less ideal materials for semiconduction)

   #### Decided to edit in based on Spehro's comment above:
5. Buyers of individual LEDs (in most 'western' areas) don't care as much about non-Arsenic/Non-Indium, etc

So you'd end up being back at paying >=$1 for a single LED, which offers the same amount of light as a begin of the century White LED, in a package in which LEDs get made with tens to hundreds of times the output at $0.05 a piece.

That's not really a great deal to make, is it?

OLEDs have great advantages when you use them for displays, because it's possible to grow them in a usable formation and the materials used offer some manner of flexibility (both in management/bio-factors and mechanically), but they are far from the efficiency of just making a wafer of Aluminium/Gallium/Arsenic/Phosphide/Indium/etc in whatever combination gives the best amount of light.

And "we" in "the west" still want to have the entire world for a dime, so nobody is about to go ahead and offer that deal.